# resize toolbar in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm adding a series of buttons to a UINavigationBar using:

```
    NSArray *items;

        items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 fixedSpace,
                 refreshStopBarButtonItem,
                 flexibleSpace,
                 self.backBarButtonItem,
                 flexibleSpace,
                 self.forwardBarButtonItem,
                 flexibleSpace,
                 self.actionBarButtonItem,
                 fixedSpace,
                 nil];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, toolbarWidth, 44.0f)];

    toolbar.items = items;

    toolbar.tintColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0];

    toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
```

All working well.

However when I rotate to landscape mode the toolbar within the uinavigationbar doesn't rotate.

Adding this code (found on SO) causes the toolbar to resize but not the buttons within it, so they are partially cropped at the bottom and no longer lines up with the toolbar background

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect navigationToolbarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    CGRect customToolbarFrame = CGRectOffset(navigationToolbarFrame, 0.0, navigationToolbarFrame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        //self.toolbar.frame = customToolbarFrame;
        // FAILS!!!
        //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.toolbar.frame = customToolbarFrame;
        // FAILS!!!
    }];
}
```

What is the correct way to address the toolbar within the uinavigationbar?
Something like...

```
self.toolbar.frame = customToolbarFrame;
```

Or do I have to specify a autoresizemask for the UIBarButtonItems?...

```
self.backBarButtonItem.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

... trying to do so like this fails

Comment: By the way, it's a long shot, but if you're adding your main view by creating the controller, grabbing its view and adding it as a subview of the parent view, that can result in rotation events not being passed correctly. See point 5 of my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Very curious because this code rotates toolbar fine when I include it in my code. No problem rotating the toolbar.
2. I assume your view controller is responding to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`? Could you include screen snapshot of what you're seeing?
3. Are you doing any `UIToolbar` category/subclass to eliminate its border? (I just subclass with empty `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` to get rid of border, but I tried both that and the standard `UIToolbar` and both rotated fine.) Anyway, if you're doing subclass/category of `UIToolbar`, please include that code?
4. Also, you could alternatively just use iOS 5's `rightBarButtonItems` and bypass the toolbar altogether, e.g. `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = items;` will then add the array of UIBarButtonItem objects to the navigation bar.
5. This is a bit of a long shot, but how is your view controller being loaded? Some people try bypassing `presentViewControllerAnimated` and/or `pushViewController` and instead simply create a view controller, grab its view, add it as a subview of the previous view controller's view. Unfortunately, this ends up with a disconnect between the view controller hierarchy and the view hierarchy, and according to [WWDC 2011 session 102](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) on view controller containment, this can prevent rotation events from being transmitted correctly. Make sure you're using `presentViewControllerAnimated` or `pushViewController` if this isn't your root view controller.

I don't do any of that `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` or subsequent code, just the simple UIToolbar and it works fine during rotation, so I wonder if the problem rests elsewhere.

Comment: Definitely quirky but your suggestion of ios5 solved it once client agree to stop supporting 4.7 for latest upgrade - thank you!